# Computer turns on when turned off

Tags: shutdown

First off, the reason I am asking this and not Googling it is because it is slightly different than the problem everybody else seems to have.

When my computer is turned off. It randomly boots up until the fans are running, then turns off again. It does this every 5 minutes or so, until I press the power button, then it just boots normally.

Is it possible this is because of a setting in BIOS? Or is it maybe something I connected wrong?

Comment: Is this a new build? Has it worked properly before?

Comment: No it never has worked properly. I have checked(and let a friend check) the wiring though, seems like everything is the way it should be.